# Get array of dates given 2 dates using MomentJs in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, momentjs

Currently i'm importing Moment and Moment range as below,
Need the array of dates between given 2 dates so that dates can be iterated

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import {extendMoment} from 'moment-range';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class T extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const start = moment("2018-10-14", 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const end = moment("2018-10-20", 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const range = moment.range(start, end);
    //need an array of dates in'YYYY-MM-DD' to itarate
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at moment-range's [`by`](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#by) that _Iterate over your range by a given period._

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the start date and add one day at a time, pushing a formatted date to an array.

By using a while loop and `isBefore` you can ensure you keep iterating until you're at the end date.

You might want to make sure this behaves correctly at the boundaries of your start and end. I.e.: do you want it to include or exclude the input days?

```js
const start = moment("2018-10-14", 'YYYY-MM-DD');
const end = moment("2018-10-20", 'YYYY-MM-DD');

const current = start.clone();
const result = [];

while (current.isBefore(end)) {
  result.push(current.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  current.add(1, "day");
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking since you already have `moment-range` you would do something like this:

```
const range = moment.range(moment("2018-10-14"), moment("2018-10-20"));

console.log(Array.from(range.by('day')).map(x => x.format('YYYY-MM-DD')))
```

If you do not need to format right away it would simply be:

```
Array.from(range.by('day'))  // for your range
```

Here is an [example in node](https://repl.it/@akrion/UnsteadyJuicySnake) but it would be similar in your case just import `by`