# Get last 7 days' dates as an array from today's date using momentJs, ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

with reference to  [my last quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944166/get-array-of-dates-given-2-dates-using-momentjs-in-reactjs) how to get previous dates from given date

```js
let n=8
        while(n>0){
            console.log(n)
            resultDates.push(moment().subtract(1,"day"))
            n--;
            
        }
       
        console.log(resultDates);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you expect? Array of dates? And show your code where you tried to solve that?

Comment: .format returns a string, so you're trying to run subtract on string

Comment: edited with corrections, getting same dates

Comment: got the solution!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const current = moment()
        let n=8
        while(n>0){
            console.log(n)
            resultDates.push(current.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
            current.subtract(1,"day")
            n--;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Modern ecmascript approach

```js
const today = moment();
const res = Array(7).fill().map(
  () => today.subtract(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI that moment has an official plugin ([**it is in their documentation**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/)) in regards to ranges which makes what you are trying to achieve easy via (nodejs for example):

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

const range = moment.range(moment().subtract(8,"day"), moment());

console.log(Array.from(range.by('day')))
```

That would give you an output like:

```
[ moment("2018-10-16T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-17T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-18T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-19T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-20T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-21T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-22T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-23T17:08:21.560"),
  moment("2018-10-24T17:08:21.560") ]
```